# Google Pagespeed Module installation issues in ubuntu

Tags: regex, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, pagespeed

I am a newbie on server side.I have put my app(implemented a website with the help of angularjs) on amazon EC2 and have installed nginx and thin on it

I am having issues with angularjs with respect to performance.

So I decide to install Pagespeed with recommendation of my seniors.

I am following the steps from https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source
and https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed.

However I am stuck at a point.The point is `./configure --add-module=$HOME/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.7.30.3-beta`

I dont know the meaning of ./configure.I dont have such a file or directory in nginx path

Also I had installed nginx before so I skipped the part where we have to install nginx server.

Also I have installed the pagespeed module in root directory and nginx on etc/nginx..

Is this why it is giving me issues and how do I solve this.Do I need to reinstall Nginx

Am very confused .

Can someone please help me.

Comment: what does the error say when you run ./configure?

Comment: @KraneBird
-bash:./configure no such file or directory

Comment: you have to `cd` inside the directory that you downloaded & extract then you can run this command, this an executable file that comes with your package, it prepares the package to be built.

Comment: @KraneBird Which diectory are you talking about..Nginx or pagespeed.
Neither has ./configure file present

Comment: I'm talking about this `cd nginx-1.4.4/` does this directory exist?

Comment: @KraneBird yes nginx is installed in etc folder..However I dont have nginx-1.4.4/ folder as I had installed nginx before

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49024/discussion-between-sanjay-salunkhe-and-kranebird)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @M42 Do you have any idea about this

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe: No, sorry. But ask your question at the address I've given.

Comment: @M42 Ok all I want is the solution..Thanks.Do I need to delete from here